# Регулярное выражения для парсинга UTC

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу составить выражени, которое будет принимать часы в UTC формате.... Т.е. часы от -12 до +14.... Помогите!

Вот примерный текст для парсинга:

```
<UTC>-9</UTC>
<UTC>9</UTC>
<UTC>+1589</UTC>
<UTC>-14</UTC>
<UTC>+12</UTC>
<UTC>10</UTC>
<UTC>14</UTC>
<UTC>12</UTC>
<UTC>10</UTC>
<UTC>14</UTC>
<UTC>15</UTC>
<UTC>-1416</UTC>
<UTC>+21sdf</UTC>
```

Comment: (-12)|(-11)| ... |(+14) не устроит?

Comment: @Nikola Tesla, что-то не работает

Comment: Извиняюсь, невнятно выразился.Я имел ввиду: ^(-12|-11|-10|-9|-8|-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|-0|\+0|\+1|\+2|\+3|\+4|\+5|\+6|\+7|\+8|\+9|\+10|\+11|\+12|\+13|\+14)$

Comment: ну, или тоже самое, но короче: ^([-+]([0-9]|10|11|12)|\+13|\+14)$

Comment: @NikolaTesla Тогда уж `^([-+](\d|1[012])|\+1[34])$`

Comment: Господа,как Вам это:  (\+?(1[0-4]|\d))|(^(\+)?\d)|(-?(1[0-4]|\d))

Comment: @nightin_gale Длинновато и позволяет -14.

Comment: @Mike,  дада, я чет с диапазоном спутал.... Но Ваше не работает = (

Comment: @nightin_gale Работает, но `+` обязателен. У вас может быть без него ?

Comment: @Mike, согласен, короче, но я не ставил цели написать максимально коротко, хотел лишь идею оформить :) Если автор подтвердит, можете оформить как ответ.

Comment: @Mike, да, может быть без него

Comment: @nightin_gale Ну так добавьте вопросов. `^([-+]?(\d|1[012])|\+?1[34])$`

Comment: @Mike, хоть режьте меня, но он не находит ни 10, ни +12, ни -12.... Попробуйте сами)

Comment: @nightin_gale https://regex101.com/r/kX7lP7/1

Comment: @Mike, ну попробуйте саме на примере текста, который я привел в вопросе :)

Comment: @nightin_gale А у вас текста до этого не было. Выражение выбирает просто то что вы сказали изначально. А что бы парсить из текста добавляйте в выражение поиск ваших тегов <utc> вместо ^ и $ ну и глобальный многострочный режим поиска включайте (включение которого зависит от языка на котором вы работаете с регулярками)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, оптимальный ли ответ или нет, но он находит все указанные числа:

```
(\+?(1[0-2]|\d))|(^\+\d)|(-?(1[0-4]|\d))
```

или вот это:

```
(\-(?:1[0-2]|\d)|\+?(?:1[0-4]|\d))
```